# What is the difference between the Congressional Record and the Federal Register?

Tags: united-states, congress

Both the Congressional Record and the Federal Register seem to be daily publications of US government - how are they different?

Would i be right in assuming that the Congressional Record is official, transcripts, whereas the Federal Register is unofficial commentary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they have different things. The Congressional Record, as its name suggests, is a record of *congressional* matters. It has things like transcripts of floor speeches and committee proceedings. The Federal Register is for the executive branch, and has things like proposed agency rules and regulations.